# Setting row height of table won't let me change color of navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a PFQueryTableViewController (a table view controller made by parse.com that can automatically make queries to their service. I have the following `init` and `viewDidLoad` methods to work totally fine:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // This table displays items in the Todo class
        self.parseClassName = @"Todos"
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Todos";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

This works completely fine, but once i set the row height in the `init` method, the navigation bar will no longer set to blue:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"Todos";
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Todos";
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 60;
    }
    return self;
}
```

The height of the rows is successfully being set, but does anyone know how I can keep them set without losing the blue color for the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad practice to access views in `init` methods that can lead to unpredictable results. Move `tableView.rowHeight` configuration to `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 60;
}
```